# Sign in from browser not working on any application

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, snap

I tried nordvpn, slack, and now github from android studio. Whenever I try to use an application that provides me a login link, I click it, log in on the browser, and click 'ok' or 'submit'. Then, either a terminal flashes up and quickly disappears, or nothing happens at all.

I've set both chrome and firefox as default browsers, so it's not that. I thought it was just a problem with the individual apps, but now that it's happened to every application, I'm not so sure about that.

Potentially relevant info:

- this is a brand new installation of ubuntu, on a new (to me) laptop.
- these are all snap packages, firefox was updated via apt upgrade

Comment: Check your logs: /var/log/syslog and journalctl.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to sign in to Slack snap app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193668/unable-to-sign-in-to-slack-snap-app)

Answer (score 0):

It is likely trying to open a custom (For slack, `slack://`) to link to the app, but, Snap is not allowing that to happen

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1246884/1133128) explains what is the issue and what can be done